# Datastoreindex-Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created new application  and deployed,in admin console Datastore index contains

block_id ▲ , board_id ▲ , branch_id ▲ , input ▲ , school_id ▲ , sec_id ▲ , std_id ▲ , sub_id▲

Serving

block_id ▲ , board_id ▲ , branch_id ▲ , input ▲ , school_id ▲ , sec_id ▲ , sub_id ▲ , std_id ▲

Serving

block_id ▲ , board_id ▲ , branch_id ▲ , input ▲ , school_id ▲ , std_id ▲ , sub_id ▲ , sec_id ▲

Serving

block_id ▲ , branch_id ▲ , input ▲ , school_id ▲ , sec_id ▲ , std_id ▲ , sub_id ▲ , board_id ▲

Serving

board_id ▲ , branch_id ▲ , input ▲ , school_id ▲ , sec_id ▲ , std_id ▲ , sub_id ▲ , block_id ▲

Serving

But again i created another application in google app engine and deployed the same program but i n that Datastore index not contain the above ,How that came?Why this not found in new application

Thanks in Advance

Comment: consider accepting some answers to your previous questions, to motivate people to help you out

Answer (score 1):

The indexes are created by the local dev server when you do some test runs on it.  Its likely that you uploaded the first application after a few test runs on the local dev server and the second one without any test runs.